# Use try-with-resources or close this "BufferedReader" in a "finally" clause in sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarqube

I was trying to implement this code but was getting some "Use try-with-resources or close this "BufferedReader" in a "finally" clause" in **sonarqube** i have already read other's answer but none of them helped me, so can anyone please guide me where exactly i have to do code changes(Really don't have any background for above error in sonarqube)

```java
     public static List getlockList(String componentPath) throws IOException 
     {
         List<String> listOfLines = new ArrayList<String>();
         BufferedReader bufReader = null;
         try {
              bufReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(componentPath));
              String line = bufReader.readLine();

              //Looking for the pattern starting with #(any number of #) then any String after that
              Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(^[#]*)(.*)");

              while (line != null) {
                  line = line.trim();
                  if(!("".equals(line))) 
                  {
                      if(line.matches("^#.*"))
                      {
                          Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
                          if (m.find( )) 
                          {
                              //System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
                              unlockList.add(m.group(2).trim());
                          }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listOfLines.add(line);
                        //empty lines removed 
                    }

                    line = bufReader.readLine();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    line = bufReader.readLine();
                  }
             }
         } catch(Exception ex) {
             log.info(ex);
         } finally {
             if (bufReader != null) 
                 bufReader.close();
         }

         return listOfLines;
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked up the term "[try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)" ?

Answer (score 2):

The BufferedReader should be created in a try-block similar to this:

```
public static List getlockList(String componentPath) throws IOException 
 {
  List<String> listOfLines = new ArrayList<String>();
  try(BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( componentPath)))
  {
      // do your magic
  }

  return listOfLines;
}
```

The Reader will be closed automatically even if an exception occur. There is also a description of the rule which covers a compliant solution: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/java8/RSPEC-2093

Comment: finally is not required for try-with-resources

Comment: Haha, duh. My bad ... @Alex

Comment: @alex but in sonarqube description they have clearly written close it with finally, i have modified it accordingly

Comment: @RajatKrishnan No, they say "Use try-with-resources **or** close this "BufferedReader" in a "finally" clause". Pay attention to "or". Both approaches work, but using try-with-resources is better than using a finally clause manually.

Comment: @alex i will go with your approach and will get back to u,Thanks for quick respone!!

Answer (score 1):

The whole logic for reading file lines must be surrounded with try catch block. This is because you can get exception like `FileNotFoundException` and so on. After you read the lines you have to close your buffer reader in `final` clause because if there is exception thrown then the `BufferedReader` might not be closed and you will have a memory leak problems.

You can use also try with resources which is new way of handling closable resources like `BufferedReader`. Then you do not need to call `bufReader.close();`

Here is oracle documentation with examples:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @Fildor you mean something like the above modified code?

Comment: @RajatKrishnan Yes, that's one way to do it. But you shouldn't change the question's code. That can lead to confusion for later readers.